# How about we use Latex in this community?

Tags: discussion

[Latex](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LaTeX) is a text formatting add-on. It is mainly used for writing mathematical expressions in electronic documents. However, on the other hand, it has very useful text formatting features, like creating tables, aligning text, reducing text size for creating foot notes, etc. Some SE communities are [already using](https://electronics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/434/test-the-new-latex-markdown-in-this-sandbox-question) it.

If you had never heard about it or never used it, it may not mean a lot to you. But if you know Latex, please share your opinions here.

Comment: What use would we have for it?

Comment: Which SE sites use it other than Mathematics and TeX?

Comment: @Gigili Chem and physics SE

Comment: You may not like my suggestion, but why are you giving me negative votes? If you like or don't like my suggestion please state it in an answer. Vote down if you find the question problematic and/or inappropriate.

Comment: @AhmedHan: Downvoting on meta means *I, for one, disagree with your suggestion and didn't find it useful*.

Comment: @AhmedHan The logistics of voting differ between meta and main-site. See here: http://meta.islam.stackexchange.com/faq#vote-differences

Comment: You might want to see this: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/73566/is-there-any-markdown-to-create-tables . This is a problem across all meta sites and is not exclusive to Islam.SE. Personally, I think Reddit-style Markdown wouldn't be bad, but it might hurt mobile user experience.

Answer (score 3):

I really think we don't need it. If we allow it here, there'll be problems regarding using, misusing, overusing it since a few percent of users might be familiar with it. Even there on mathematics.SE there are many problems as to which feature is appropriate in which situation. There are questions on meta.SO on drawing tables and such, we can choose one if we really need to draw a graphical table. We can even use a software and upload the image here. I think it'll make the site more messy than neat.